# Complete Lattice and Concept Lattice

Tags: formal-languages, lattice-orders

I am taking an online course of Introduction to Formal Concept Analysis and I'm trying to understand **The Basic Theorem**.

Well, if $\mathscr{L}$ is a complete lattice, so $\mathscr{L}\cong \underline{\mathfrak{B}}(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{L},\leq)$ (concept lattice of context $(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{L},\leq)$).

And we know that:

(*) All concept lattice are complete lattice.

My question is: When we define a formal context $(G,M,I)$, the sets $G,M$ don't have 'conditions'. What happens when I take a non-complete lattice $\mathscr{L}$ and define the formal context $(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{L},\leq)$? Can I do this? If yes, so $\underline{\mathfrak{B}}(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{L},\leq)$ is **not** $\mathscr{L}$?

For instance. Take a non-complete lattice $(\mathbb{N},\leq$) and the formal context $(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N},\leq)$. And about the concept lattice of this context?

Thanks for a help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formal concepts can be identified with certain subsets of $G$ (specifically with the *closed* subsets in the *Galois connection* induced by $I$), which are closed under taking arbitrary intersections. 
Note that it is happening in the already complete lattice of the *power set*.

The case $(\mathcal L, \mathcal L, \le)$ with $\mathcal L$ a complete lattice is special. Then, for subsets $A, B\subseteq\mathcal L$ we have
$$\forall a\in A,\,b\in B\, (a\le b) \ \iff\ \bigvee A\le\bigwedge B$$
so that the subsets can be represented by single elements.

Comment: Berci, thank you very much for the answer. I don't know if because I don't have much knowing... But I don't understand very well the relation between your answer and my doubt about, for instance, the concept lattice $(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}, \leq)$, remembering that $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ is NOT a complete lattice. So, $\underline{\mathfrak{B}}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ is a complete lattice and it's NOT similar to $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$...? How can I see this...? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, in the case of $\Bbb N$, it will be very similar to $\Bbb N$, basically only that it's extended by an $\infty$ element that makes the lattice complete, namely by the concept $(\Bbb N, \emptyset)$. All other concepts are of the form $(\{0,1,\dots, n\},\, \{n, n+1,\dots\})$ for some $n$, which can be identified by $\Bbb N$. For a general lattice/poset, the extent is always downward closed, and the intent is upward closed.

Comment: Oh, $(\mathbb{N},\emptyset)$... So, the professor says: "$(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ is not a complete lattice because $\mathbb{N}$ don't have a supremum"... So, if I understood right, the case is following: When I use sup in definition of complete lattice, I presume that this sup is ON the set (in this case, 
 it would be $\mathbb{N}$). However, this don't occur, because the unique sup I could take is $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ isn't an element of $\mathbb{N}$. Altough, I can take the concept $(\mathbb{N},\emptyset)$... It's a little confused, rs... But I thank you very much for the great help!